# Get only Objects which get match from other Array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having a two array of objects,

```
let list = [
    {
        "currency": "Albania Lek",
        "abbreviation": "ALL",
    },
    {
        "currency": "Afghanistan Afghani",
        "abbreviation": "AFN",
    },
    {
        "currency": "Argentina Peso",
        "abbreviation": "ARS",
    }];

let c = [
    {
        "value": "AFN"
    },
    {
        "value": "ARS"
    }] 
let asd = list.filter(l=>{
    return l.abbreviation === c.forEach(x=>x.sCurrencyName)
})
```

i want to return only those object from `list` which has value in Array of object `c`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` with `.some()` method:

```js
let list = [
    {"currency": "Albania Lek", "abbreviation": "ALL"},
    {"currency": "Afghanistan Afghani", "abbreviation": "AFN"},
    {"currency": "Argentina Peso", "abbreviation": "ARS"}
];

let c = [{"value": "AFN"}, {"value": "ARS"}];
    
let result = list.filter(
  ({ abbreviation }) => c.some(({ value }) => value === abbreviation)
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` doesn't return a value that can be used. So when you write `l.abbreviation === c.forEach...`, there's nothing on the right side of the `===` sign.

A naive solution would be to use the `Array#some` function. This function returns a boolean value based on the condition specified, which is what you need here.

So your code becomes

```
let asd = list.filter(litem => c.some(citem => citem.value === litem.abbreviation))
```

You can read more about all the different methods available on arrays @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array